# Как правильно переносить(копировать) элемент одного std::vector в другой

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Интересует как быстрее всего копировать или переносить элементы из одного std::vector в другой, раньше для возможности быстрого удаления элементов из контейнера использовал std::list

```
        for( auto it=l.begin(); it!=l.end();) {
            if ( условие )
                it=l.erase(it);
            else
               ++it;
        }
```

но как оказалось list не слишком быстрый даже в этом, теперь использую нечто вроде

```
        for( auto it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
            if ( !условие )
                tmpv.emplace_back(*it);
        }
        v.swap(tmpv);
        tmpv.clear();
```

сначало элементы которые не попали под условие переношу в другой vector, а потом меняю контейнеры местами, но мне кажется что

```
                tmpv.emplace_back(*it);
```

это не совсем правильно и возможно есть другие функции в std которые позволят переносить(копировать) элемент быстрее чем реализовано у меня

Comment: Какое количество элементов в векторе?
"Старый" вектор после операции подлежит удалению.
В векторе случайно не лежат указатели?

Comment: @gbg в этом контейнере обычно до 6000 элементов, но постоянно добавляются новые и удаляются по условию те, что уже не нужны. Добавление и удаление элементов проиходит в цикле на примерно 5млн  итераций. В векторе хранятся объекты класса,каждый размером 32байта, оба вектора и основной и вспомогательный создаются до цикла. в цикле есть только очистка вспомогательного вектора.

Comment: Подумайте над тем, чтобы реализовать для своих элементов move-семантику. И применить вытеснение нужных элементов в начало вектора, как ниже советуют.

Comment: Может вам всё-таки нужен не вектор, а список? Если операция добавления и удаления будут происходить достаточно часто. Почему вам нужен именно вектор?

Comment: @cybrex, потому что он тупо быстрее. те способы что я привел в вопросе, время работы: list-8000ms, vector-3000ms. это кажется что список лучше а на самом деле берешь и проверяешь.

Comment: Что подразумевается под "работой" время которой оценивалось? Заполнили вектор, и что с ним делают дальше? Я просто пытаюсь лучше понять исходную задачу.

Comment: @cybrex тестовая программа: в цикле на 5млн итераций, каждую итерацию в контейнер добаляется 10 новых элементов, и в каждой 10 итерации цикла удаляется каждый 10 элемент контейнера.

Comment: @xttz, я правильно понял, что за 10 итераций в конец вектора добавляются 100 элементов, потом (на последней из этих 10) удаляется каждый 10-й, (кстати, включая и вновь добавленные ?) т.о. после 10 итераций в векторе 90 элементов, а после 5млн. в нем 45млн. элементов? / А в предыдущем комментарии Вы пишете, что `в этом контейнере обычно до 6000 элементов`. / Чему верить (какой вариант тестируем)?

Comment: Может опишете задачку (если Вам и впрямь хочется ее решить) потолковей?

Comment: Это не задача, я просто выбирал как это более эффективно реализовать в программе обрабоку данных, а это был просто тестовый код, для сравнения работы вектора и списка, какими бы не были эти параметры (кол-во, добавляемых элементов, итерация на которой происходит удаление, количество удаляемых элементов)  список оказывается медленней вектора, всегда. это скорее всего связано с тем что добавление элементов в вектор в разы быстрее добавления их в список.

Comment: @xttz, если порядок обработки и относительное расположение элементов в векторе после нее не важны, то процесс можно ускорить раза в полтора, двигаясь по вектору с двух концов. На всякий случай приведу примерчик в обновлении своего ответа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А самый простой вариант (оставляет элементы соответствующие `cond()`)

```
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    if (condition(v[i]))
      v[n++] = v[i];
  v.resize(n);
```

не пробовали?

---

Если порядок обработки и относительное расположение элементов в векторе после нее не важны, то процесс можно ускорить раза в полтора (если затраты на вычисление условия, копирование элемента и обработку удаляемого одинаковы).

Вот примерчик:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

void act (string s) {
  cout << s << '\n';
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[]) 
{
  vector<string> v;
  string s;

  while (cin >> s)
    v.push_back(s);
  cout << "size: " << v.size() << " capacity: " << v.capacity() << '\n';
  int n = 0, cntcmp = 0, cntcpy = 0, cntact = 0;
  if (av[1]) {
    /*
      size: 108 capacity: 256
      cmp: 120 cpy: 64 act: 140 total: 324
     */
    n = v.size();

    int i = 0, j = v.size() - 1;

    while (j >= i) {
      while (i <= j && isalpha(v[i][0])) {
        cntcmp++;
        i++;
      }
      if (i > j)
        break;
      act(v[i]);
      cntact++;
      n--;
      while (j > i && !isalpha(v[j][0])) {
        cntcmp++;
        cntact++;
        act(v[j--]);
        n--;
      }
      if (j == i)
        break;
      v[i++] = v[j--];
      cntcpy++;
    }
  } else {
    /*
      size: 108 capacity: 256
      cmp: 248 cpy: 108 act: 140 total: 496
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
      cntcmp++;
      if (isalpha(v[i][0])) {
        cntcpy++;
        v[n++] = v[i];
      } else {
        cntact++;
        act(v[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  v.resize(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << v[i] << '\n';

  cerr << "size: " << v.size() << " capacity: " << v.capacity() << '\n';
  cerr << "cmp: " << cntcmp << " cpy: " << cntcpy << " act: " << cntact 
       << " total: " << cntcmp + cntact + cntcpy << '\n';
}
```

Вот результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ c.cpp 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out   < c.cpp | sort >2.txt
size: 108 capacity: 256
cmp: 248 cpy: 108 act: 140 total: 496
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 1  < c.cpp | sort >1.txt
size: 108 capacity: 256
cmp: 120 cpy: 64 act: 140 total: 324
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cmp 1.txt 2.txt
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Ну, все эти sort и cmp для того, чтобы убедиться, что оба варианта дают тот же результат.

Comment: спасибо, это самый быстрый вариант из всех!

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, класс `std::list` имеет специальные функции члены класса `remove` и `remove_if`, которые позволяют выполнить данную операцию для списка за один вызов функции:

```
void remove(const T& value);
template <class Predicate> void remove_if(Predicate pred);
```

Что касается вектора, то я думаю, что вместо того, чтобы удалять каждый элемент, удовлетворяющий заданному условию, по отдельности в цикле, значительно более эффективно использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::remove_if` в связке с методом вектора `erase`. Например,

```
v.erase( std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), []( const auto &x ) { return condition( x ); } ), 
         v.end() );
```

Если же вы с удаляемыми элементами производите какие-то дополнительные операции, то вы просто можете реализацию алгоритма `std::remove_if` использовать в своем коде в виде цикла и в этот цикл вставить те дополнительные операции, которые вам необходимо проделать над элементами.

На мой взгляд это более эффективно, чем копировать элементы вектора в другой вектор, так как это не требует выделение дополнительной памяти и вызова деструкторов для каждого элемента вектора при обмене векторов. И уж по крайней мере если копировать элементы вектора в другой вектор, то лучше использовать `move` итератор. Проблема может состоять в том, что объекты могут быть не перемещаемы.

Что касается этого вызова

```
tmpv.emplace_back(*it);
```

то здесь используется просто конструктор копирования, так как это единственный подходящий конструктор для аргумента `*it`. Так что никакой разницы между

```
tmpv.emplace_back(*it);
```

и

```
tmpv.push_back(*it);
```

в данном случае нет.

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl; }
    A( const A & ) { std::cout << "A::A( const A &)" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A::~A()" << std::endl; }
};   

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v1( 1, A() );

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;

    std::vector<A> v2;

    v2.emplace_back( *std::begin( v1 ) );
//    v2.push_back( *std::begin( v1 ) );

    std::cout << "-------------------" << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
A::A()
A::A( const A &)
A::~A()
-------------------
A::A( const A &)
-------------------
A::~A()
A::~A()
```

Comment: это было бы проще, вот только у меня не просто удаление элемента из контейнера, перед его удалением из его праметров генерируется элемент другого класса и добавляется в свой контейнер.

Comment: @xttz Желательно в вопросе указывать подобного рода нюансы. Потому что в результате получается на самом деле два разных вопроса. Один - как удалить элементы контейнера, а другой - как создать элементы другого класса, непонятно как связанные с удалением элементов из вектора.

Comment: @xttz И код, который вы привели абсолютно никак не указывает на какие-то побочные операции с контейнером.

Comment: ну вопрос вообще то был в том, что emplace_back(*it); как мне кажется неправильно использовать, и соответственно на что его можно заменить

Comment: @xttz Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Какой-то "размытый" вопрос... Можно например так:

```
std::vector <int> src{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector <int> dst;

// ...

std::copy_if( src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter( dst ), []( const int & i ){ return i > 3; } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, что в вашей задаче происходит копирование по десять элементов. То наверное и нужно копировать по десять элементов сразу. Точно не уверен в скорости моего решения просто проверьте быстрее оно или нет. И сильно не ругайте если я не прав это эксперимент.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int size = 50; // размер массива
    vector<int> a; // из которого копируем
    vector<int> b; // основной в который пишем

    srand(time(0)); // рандомизация генератора

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){  // заполняем массив значениями
        a.push_back(rand() % 100); // из котрого будем копировать
    }

    vector<int>::iterator start = a.begin(), end = a.begin(); // переменные для начала и конца копирования

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 10){ // копирование по десять элементов
        end += 10; // передвигаем счетчик конца на 10 элементов
        start = end - 10; // находим начало откуда копировать
        b.resize(i + 10); // увеличиваем вместимость вектора
        std::copy(start, end, b.begin() + i); // копируем по десять элементов в другой массив
        // здесь если вы захотите можете удалять каждый десятый элемент как у вас в задании
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){ // проверка
        cout << b[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```